# How to create inline buttons for telegram bot in php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

[image]

I want to make a inline buttons like these. The problem is callback values are not working at all. Hope someone can help me.

```
<?php
$botToken = "......"; // Enter ur bot token
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
error_reporting(0);
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$print = print_r($update);
$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$gId = $update["message"]["from"]["id"];
$userId = $update["message"]["from"]["id"];
$firstname = $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
$username = $update["message"]["from"]["username"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];
$message_id = $update["message"]["message_id"];

//////////=========[Start Command]=========//////////

if ((strpos($message, "!start") === 0)||(strpos($message, "/start") === 0)){
    $response = "Hello $firstname!";

    $keyboard = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
        [
            ['text' => 'COMMANDS', 'callback_data' => 'someString']
        ]
    ]
];
$encodedKeyboard = json_encode($keyboard);
$parameters = 
    array(
        'chat_id' => $chatId, 
        'text' => $response, 
        'reply_markup' => $encodedKeyboard
    );

send('sendMessage', $parameters);
}

function send($method, $data)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot-Token>". "/" . $method;

    if (!$curld = curl_init()) {
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close($curld);
    return $output;
}

}




function sendMessage ($chatId, $message){
$url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message."&reply_to_message_id=".$message_id."&parse_mode=HTML";
file_get_contents($url);      
}
?>
```

The button is working fine, but not showing any output, or any value. Can somebody please help me with it

Comment: Can someone help with the code

Answer (score 1):

you can get CallbackQuery updstes like this

```
$callback_update = $update["callback_query"];
$c_back_userID = $callback_update["from"]["id"];
$c_back_msg = $callback_update["message"]["text"];
```